# Linux Socket::connect and QT::connect mixed

Tags: linux, qt, sockets, connect

i am writing a program with Qt.I have class derived from QWidget.in it's constructor i want to use Linux Socket connect method .and also want to use Qt connect Signal & Slot method .
how can i do this .because when i use Socket connect method compiler think i'm using Signal_Slot connect method and give compile error that argument doesn't match and ....

Thanks for any info you may be able to provide.

this is my code:

```
Login_Page::Login_Page(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::Login_Page){

ui->setupUi(this);
ui->error_lablel->hide();
//try connect to server
...
if(connect(client_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))){
    ui->login_button->setDisabled(true);
    ui->error_lablel->setText("cannot connect to server");
    ui->error_lablel->show();
    while(true){
        if(!(connect(client_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))))
           break;
    }
    ui->login_button->setDisabled(false);
    ui->error_lablel->hide();
}

connect(ui->login_button,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(login()));
```

}

Comment: Can you paste your error message?

Comment: error: no matching function for call to 'Login_Page::connect(int&, sockaddr*, unsigned int)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the connect method of socket with `::` prefix :

```
...
if(::connect(client_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))){
...
```